# Convert matrix of lists (each of length 1) to normal matrix, retaining dimensions

Tags: r, list, matrix

So I seem to have gotten some faulty data, and I would like to extract the data into a more usable state as the calculations will take another day to run. Currently I have a matrix of lists, where each list only contains 1 number. Is it possible to remove each value from the list into a matrix with the same dimensions? Here is a representation of what the output looks like.

```
filler = 0
for(j in  1:2){
    for(i in 1:10){
        filler[i] <- as.list(i)
    }
    if(j == 1){
        final <- filler
    }else{
        final <- cbind(final,filler)
    }
}
final <- data.matrix(final)
```

Here is what the output looks like

```
> final[1,1]
$final
[1] 1

> final
      final filler
[1,] 1     1     
[2,] 2     2     
[3,] 3     3     
[4,] 4     4     
[5,] 5     5     
[6,] 6     6     
[7,] 7     7     
[8,] 8     8     
[9,] 9     9     
[10,] 10    10
```

Comment: This? `matrix(unlist(final), nrow = nrow(final), dimnames = dimnames(final))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix of lists (each of length 1) `final`  can be converted to a normal matrix using

```
matrix(unlist(final), nrow = nrow(final), dimnames = dimnames(final))
```

`unlist` returns a numeric vector, which is then converted to a new matrix, using the number of rows and `dimnames` of the original matrix.